# Converting multiple rows to single key value pair row/column in Big query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want convert the multiple rows of data into key value pairs. Was able to do this in hive using udaf function

Input table has two columns

column1 column2

1 23

2 30

3 45

4 50

5 65

output table will have one row/column

Weeksales(key,value)

(“1”:”23",”2":”30",”3":”45",”4":”50",”5":”65")

Comment: Just one row in output table?

Comment: Yes. Just edited the question.

Comment: This quite simple! Have you even tried something?

Comment: New to GCP world. Tried few things, could not achieve the expected output, Hence posted it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT CONCAT('{',
    STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', CAST(column1 AS STRING), '":"', CAST(column2 AS STRING), '"')),
  '}') AS Weeksales
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data from your question  - result will be

```
Row Weeksales    
1   {"1":"23","2":"30","3":"45","4":"50","5":"65"}
```

Or less verbose version

```
#standardSQL
SELECT FORMAT('{%s}', STRING_AGG(FORMAT('"%d":"%d"', column1, column2))) AS Weeksales
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

*Obviously with same output*

Yet another option, even less verbose with slightly different output - but wanted to show       as an option for you

```
#standardSQL
SELECT STRING_AGG(FORMAT('%T', t)) AS Weeksales
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

with output

```
Row Weeksales    
1   (1, 23),(2, 30),(3, 45),(4, 50),(5, 65)
```

Another variation of last version

```
#standardSQL
SELECT FORMAT('%t', ARRAY_AGG(t)) AS Weeksales
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

with output

```
Row Weeksales    
1   [(1, 23), (2, 30), (3, 45), (4, 50), (5, 65)]
```

Comment: Thanks. will try this.